# Flutter bloc and angular observable data services

Tags: flutter, bloc

i’m New to flutter and i’m learning to use bloc pattern.

Do you find that bloc pattern share the same approach like angular does with observable data services?

https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services